# XSLT when desired input and output xslt are same

Tags: xslt

From the [link](http://xslttest.appspot.com/), I need to create an XSLT where both the input and output XML should be same as below. Please suggest on how to create XSLT for below input XML to achieve same as output.

```
<abc:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <abc:Body>
      <def:CheckOutput xmlns:def="http://www.test.com/service">
         <def:Error>
            <def:Code>0</def:Code>
         </def:Error>
      </def:CheckOutput>
   </abc:Body>
</abc:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have a read up on the XSLT identity transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

Comment: What is the purpose of the transformation, if nothing is transformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml is **invalid**, cause the namespace-prefix `abc` is not defined. Namespace-prefix `NS1` is defined, but never used. Maybe your input-xml got mixed up.

With valid input, your xslt would be like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:abc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:def="http://www.test.com/service">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```